# Получить exit код при выполнении удаленной команды SSH

Tags: linux, bash

Подключаюсь по ssh с ключем verbose

```
ssh -v -p $port $name $REMOTE_COMMAND
```

и выполняю удаленную команду

```
REMOTE_COMMAND="cd ${EXTRACT_PATH} && `
               `if [[ -d /home/${VERSION} ]]; then `
               `echo Exist ; exit 12 ; `
               `else echo NotExist ; `
               `fi"
```

С помощью ключа verbose удается получить на консоле статус `debug1: Exit status 12`

Но если выполнить команду `echo $?`, то возвращает 0.

Как мне получить статус удаленного `exit` при выполнении команды `echo $?`?

Comment: А что за ОС? К примеру на centos 6,5 возвращает корректно код.

Comment: Дистрибутив debian 10.3, на котором выполняется удаленная команда. Запускаю скрипт с ubuntu 18.04

Comment: а как вы вот дошли до подобной навороченной конструкции? попробовали совсем простую, она не работает, вы попробовали её усложнить, она опять не работает, усложнили ещё, не работает вновь, и вы решили задать здесь вопрос, выложив самый навороченный неработающий вариант. так? попробуйте вернуться на самый первый шаг. что-нибудь вроде: `$ ssh -p порт пользователь@сервер exit 222; echo $?`. получили "222" в терминале? теперь начинайте усложнять, проверяя каждый следующий шаг. не получили? вот тогда и стоит задавать вопрос: ведь не работает примитивная заведомо рабочая конструкция.

Comment: Нашел причину, у меня стояла команда set -e. Соответственно при exit она срабатывала, не давая завершить сценарий до конца.

Answer (score 1):

Все работает

```sh
$ ssh user@server "echo ok; exit 12"
ok
$ echo $?
12
```